# How to implement for loop using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, iteration

This code does a small iteration and gives output as follows

code :

```
result = []
start = 1000
lst = ['20','30','50','1','200']
for i in lst:
    data = {
           "total_members_present":start,    
           "count": i,
           "total_members_now":start - int(i)
           "id":'12345'
          }
    start = data["total_members_now"]
    result.append(data)

print(result)
```

output :

```
[{'count': '20', 'total_members_now': 980, 'total_members_present': 1000,'id':'123456'},
 {'count': '30', 'total_members_now': 950, 'total_members_present': 980,'id':'123456'},
 {'count': '50', 'total_members_now': 900, 'total_members_present': 950,'id':'123456'},
 {'count': '1', 'total_members_now': 899, 'total_members_present': 900,'id':'123456'},
 {'count': '200', 'total_members_now': 699, 'total_members_present': 899,'id':'123456'}]
```

Need to use for-loop and add  list of id's

example :  id =['12345','789456']

Need to use id in for loop:

tried this :

```
 id =['12345','789456']
result = []
start = 1000
lst = ['20','30','50','1','200']

for ids  in id :

    for i in lst:
        data = {
               "total_members_present":start,    
               "count": i,
               "total_members_now":start - int(i)
               "id":ids
              }
        start = data["total_members_now"]

result.append(data)
```

required output :

for each `id` start = 1000 should reset to 1000 and it shoul start from beginning, here the loops gets going.  and for id  789456,  start should be 1000 but here it is 899.

Answer (score 0):

```
id =['12345','789456']
result = []
lst = ['20','30','50','1','200']

for ids  in id :
    start = 1000
    for i in lst:
        data = {
               "total_members_present":start,    
               "count": i,
               "total_members_now":start - int(i)
               "id":ids
              }
        start = data["total_members_now"]
        result.append(data)
```